# Position fixed element hides behind virtual buttons on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am working on some project, and after testing I have noticed that if the device has virtual buttons(on-screen), then div element that is supposed to be always fixed at the bottom, is behind those buttons. Basically I have lets say 2 divs, one is 100vw 100vh, the other one is 100vw wide and has height of 60px, instead of going above(stacked) the buttons, it goes beneath those buttons and is invisible unless the user hides his virtual buttons.

Is there a way to detect if the user has virtual buttons, and then just use some JS magic, or can it be fixed with a simple CSS solution?

Here is my code, and also JS Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/hc9fvdgc/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .example {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background: url('http://dpanoply.s3.amazonaws.com/blog/9-best-sites-for-free-stock-photos/pexels.jpg');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    .example > .toolbar {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: #b1b1b1;
        border-top: 1px solid #3b3b3b;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="example">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>TOOLBAR</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*NOTE: I do not own a smartphone with virtual buttons, so Im unable to test.*